# 7zip in Powershell keeps saying "Too long switch" or "Too short switch"

Tags: powershell, 7zip

Tried many combinations using this script to compress a lot of files into individual files using 7zip, but I keep getting errors.

```
Get-ChildItem *.smc | ForEach-Object { 7z a -yx9 -x9 "$_.Name+.7z" $_.Name }
```

Keeps coming up with "Too Long Switch" or "Too Short Switch".  What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate problems with your command:

- You're incorrectly embedding property access `$_.Name` inside `"..."`: you must use `"$($_.Name)+.7z"` - note the use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--).

  - In short: In order to embed *expressions* in an expandable string (`"..."`), you must enclose them in `$(...)`. Notably, this includes property and indexed access (e.g., `$($var.property)`, `$($var[0])`). Only variables *as a whole* do not require this (e.g., `$var`, `$env:USERNAME`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for more information.
- Your options are meant to specify *file-analysis levels* and *compression levels*, which means that they must be passed as option *arguments* to the [`-m` option](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm).

  - Therefore, use `-myx9 -mx9`

Comment: Glad to hear it, Jim.

Answer (score 0):

I used cmd /c to solve my problem with -x, eg:

```
& { cmd /c "7z a -x!.vs ..\snakepas_vs2022.zip ." }
```

Or:

```
& { 7z a "-x!.vs" ..\snakepas_vs2022.zip . }
```